# UIImagepicker not working ipad for iphone application

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I am developing an iPhone app, in my app some pages have to get images from a gallery. All working is fine on iPhone and on iPad, but I cannot always get an image through `imagePickerControllerDidCancel()`.

This method only fired event when I choose the image.. I cant find any solution for this.

Any help would be really appreciable !

```
   if (!self.takeImage) self.takeImage = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        [[self.takeImage navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

   self.takeImage.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
   self.takeImage.delegate = self;

   [self presentViewController:self.takeImage animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `UIPopoverController` to present `UIImagePickerController` on iPad

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.selectedImageView.bounds inView:self.selectedImageView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    self.popOver = popover;
} else {
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem if your ipad iOS version is less than 7.0. Try using presentPopoverFromRect: instead of presentViewController.

Here, this code might help,

```
if (([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) && SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0")) 
{
        self.popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
        [self.popOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 600.0,500.0) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                    animated:YES];
    }
    else
        [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: My app is not universal app. If i put this code my app ll crash. Because my app support only iphone.